# What to do when there is enormous large number of blkid command running?

Tags: linux, centos7

Recently I saw server is slowing down rapidly, and when I checked what is going on, I saw extremely large number of `blkid` processes and server load is enormously high. Here is the screenshot of top command:

[image: Screenshot of top command]

What to do to stop/remove those processes?

Comment: Try `sudo killall blkid`, but you will have to find out what starts these processes.

Comment: Try `pstree -ps <pid>` for any of them, to find out what has started the process.

Comment: I'm probably just being paranoid here, but check the `/proc/<procid>/exe` symlink (where `<procid>` is the process id of the `blkid` command) if it indeed points to the `blkid` command, and to the system-wide one. If the `exe` symlink doesn't point to `blkid`, or if the `blkid` it points to dwells in some suspicious directory (`/tmp/` perhaps), then your server is probably got hacked.

Comment: I have checked `/proc/<procid>/exe` on a few of them all are  `/usr/sbin/blkid` ... When I kill all blkid processes they reappear, about 20 of them. And load is still high, over 150... But after each second while watching `top` PID is always changed to all of them

Comment: when pressed C button while in `top` this is the command which is run:
`blkid -c /dev/null -o export`

Comment: pstree returns: `[root@packet ~]# pstree -ps 15465
systemd(1)───ds-identify(15458)───blkid(15465)
`

Comment: `[root@packet ~]# cloud-init status --long`
`status: disabled`
`time: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 07:10:51 +0000`
`detail: DataSourceEc2`

Comment: `journalctl -u "cloud*" -b | head -100` returns `Failed to add filter for units: No data available` and there is no cloud-init data in `/var/lib/cloud/` neither in it's instance

Comment: I found identical issues on ubuntu machine https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1856560 and tried to restart server (after almost 3 years). Problem was gone. Still wondering what happened.

Comment: *almost 3 years*? With the PIDs are quite far apart, I wonder if the number of leftover processes coincides with the number of systemd daemon-reexecs in that timespan, which might point to a separate bug in *systemd.generator* cleanup..

Comment: Anx, I'm not expert in linux systems so I don't know what are R and D states. And server was 3 years online, and this happened few days ago.